# Drupal-git-sandbox project: commits are shown but no new revision

Tags: version-control, community-official-site

I don't know why I have no new revision, what I do:
I change my code locally, then:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "bla"
git push -u origin 7.x-1.x
```

Result:

A new commit is shown in my sandbox repository on drupal.org. But I need a new revision too! I'm new to git, so can anybody explain what I misunderstand?

Answer (score 1):

Sandboxes on Drupal.org can't have releases (tagged revisions).

For a *full project*, if you want to push a specific release/revision, rather than just a SHA-identified commit, you create a tag locally before you push a tagged release.

```
git commit -am "Revision 7.x-1.0"
git tag 7.x-1.0
git push origin tag 7.x-1.0
```